# Protect angular derective via guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have kind of `ChatbotComponent` that is not attached to any route configuration.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbot',
  templateUrl: './chatbot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbot.component.css'],
  providers: [UsersService, OrganizationService]
})
```

The directive, is called under app.compononent.html covered by app module:

```
<app-logo></app-logo>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-chatbot></app-chatbot>
```

This is my routing.yaml

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},
  { path: 'accueil',  component: AccueilComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

I'm asking is there any way to protect the `ChatbotComponent` via my `AuthenticationGuard` in order to stop api calls fired under the compononent !

This is a small vision about my dependencies:

```
+-- @angular/animations@5.2.11
+-- @angular/cli@1.7.4
| +-- @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.3.2
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@0.3.2
| +-- @angular-devkit/schematics@0.3.2
| +-- @schematics/angular@0.3.2
+-- @angular/common@5.2.11
+-- @angular/compiler@5.2.11
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11
+-- @angular/core@5.2.11
+-- @angular/forms@5.2.11
+-- @angular/http@5.2.11
+-- @angular/language-service@5.2.11
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.11
+-- @angular/router@5.2.11
+-- angular-in-memory-web-api@0.5.4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `*ngIf`

```
<app-chatbot *ngIf="isAuthenticated"></app-chatbot>
```

Where you should define `isAuthenticated` in your app.component.ts and assign `true` if the user is authenticated, and `false` otherwise.

Edit:
For example in your app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) {
    }

    // Authentication service has an obsevable authenticated that emits a value when the user authentication status changes.
    // in ngOnInit subscribe to that value
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.authenticationService.authenticated$.subscribe((val) => {
             this.isAuthenticated = val;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey  @Sherid do i need to define isAuthenticated under AppComponent !! And how to related isAuthenticated with my guard !

Comment: Hey @Sherid ther's a small detail, in fact authenticationService gonna be called twice